# jQuery Newbie, need a little help

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I am in the process of recreating this feature:

http://www.w3.org/html/logo/#the-technology

I current have it so when you click on a link, it will add a class to the image that relates to that link (href="#one" on the `<a>` and then id="#one" on the `<img>`), however it is currently not going through each `<a>` tag and only one. And also it is not removing the class I requested.

Code follows:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var container = '#portfolio #text_container';

var img_container = '#portfolio #image_container';

$(container).children('a').bind('click', function() {

var this_attr = $(this).attr('href');

var this_img = $(img_container).find('img').attr('id');

if(this_attr == this_img) {

    //$(img_container).find('img').hasClass('current').removeClass('current');

        // ^^^ This line isn't working, any ideas? :/

    $(img_container + ' img[id*="' + this_attr + '"]').addClass('current');

}

else {

    alert(this_img + ' this img');

        alert(this_attr + ' this attr');

}

  });

});
```

And the HTML is as follows

```
<div id="portfolio">

    <div id="image_container">
        <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" alt="" class="current" id="#one" />
        <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/btn_downloadLarge.gif" alt="" id="#two" />
    </div>

    <div id="text_container">
        <a href="#one" class="link">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#two" class="link">Item 2</a>

        <p id="#one" class="current">A bunch of text!</p>
        <p id="#two">The second bunch of text!</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Please let me know if you need any more information :)

**rcravens fixed this with the following code..**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#text_container a').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        $('.current').removeClass('current');

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $("." + href).addClass('current');


    });
```

**And the HTML..**

```
<div id="portfolio">

    <div id="image_container">
        <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" alt="" class="one current" />
        <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/btn_downloadLarge.gif" alt="" class="two" />
    </div>

    <div id="text_container">
        <a href="one" class="link">Item 1</a>
        <a href="two" class="link">Item 2</a>

        <p class="one current">A bunch of text!</p>
        <p class="two">The second bunch of text!</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Here you can see an nice article stating the [difference between id's and classes](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of what you are trying to do is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/wMhEC/

The code is changed a bit. You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id.

Bob

Comment: Wow, that is so simple :x Yes that is exactly what I wanted - thank you! :)

Comment: Please post your solution here as well. The usefulness of Stack Overflow shouldn't be dependent upon the availability of another site.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working:

```
if(this_attr == this_img)
```

is because `this_attr` is a URL and `this_img` is an ID attribute value.